Compute the conjugate of $\varphi (t) = \frac{1}{p}|t|^p$.
I'm a bit confused on how to actually compute the conjugate on a function like this based on the definition alone. The conjugate is given by $$\varphi^*(f) = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \{f(x)-\varphi(x)\}$$
Where $f \in \mathbb{R}^*$ ($\mathbb{R}^*$ denotes the dual space of $\mathbb{R}$). I know that $f$ identifies with a point in $\mathbb{R}$ but I'm a bit confused on how to actually proceed with this. The result is supposed to be $\varphi^*(y) = \frac{1}{q}y^q$, where $q$ is such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$. Any help would be appreciated.

We work with $p>1$. Then for all $f\in \mathbb R$ the supremum exists and is attained at some $x$. Since $t \mapsto |t|^p$ is differentiable,
$x$ satisfies
$$
0=f - \phi'(x)=f-sign(x)|x|^{p-1}.
$$
That is, $x$ solves
$$
f= sign(x)|x|^{p-1}.
$$
The unique solution of this equation is given by
$$
x = sign(f) |f|^{1/(p-1)}.
$$
Plugging this into $\phi^*$ yields
$$
\phi^*(f) = fx - \phi(x) = |f|^{1/(p-1)+1} - \frac1p |f|^{p/(p-1)}
=(1-\frac1p) |f|^{p/(p-1)}
$$

How do you know that the supremum is attained at some x? Also how do you know that it is attained at an $x \neq 0$? If it is attained at 0 then the function is not differentiable

Existence: sublevel-sets are bounded. For $p>1 the function is differentiable even at $x=0$. Uniqueness follows from strict concavity.

I also have the doubt as why $f$ satisfies that $f-\phi'(x) = 0$

the function is $f\cdot x - \frac1p|x|^p$ is maximized at $x$, so its derivative is zero there...
